# Proper way to use Maven plugin in multi build variant Android project to upload artifacts

Tags: android, maven

I have an android project that uses build variants to define different builds that I frequently make (debug builds, internal release builds, instrumented apks, release builds).

When the builds are complete I upload them to a Nexus snapshot repo. To do this I apply the maven plugin in my module level build.gradle file and use the "uploadArchives" task (is it actually a task? object?) to do my upload. The problem I am facing is that different build variants produce different build artifacts however I can only define uploadArchives once so I basically only have one gradle task but many different uses for it. What I'd love to have is multiple gradle tasks for the multiple different scenarios that I run into. For example, I'd love to have an uploadInstrumentedApkToSnapshotsRepo task and a uploadReleaseApkToSnapShots repo task however AFAIK that's not possible.

Because I can't define a custom upload task per scenario I'm stuck with having to have just the uploadArchives task and then doing a bunch of conditional checks within it to define which artifacts to upload. For instance, what I've been doing is checking for the existence of certain files to determine which build variant is being built so that I can define and send the correct artifacts to Nexus. This seems wrong and way too difficult for a seemingly simple task.

Is there a way to define multiple uploadArchives tasks specific to different scenarios?

Comment: bit of an old thread, but I have a similar question. I'd settle for what you had running - conditional checks within `uploadArchives` to upload multiple aars to different repos. I don't suppose you still have this config handy that you could share a snippet for?